# Is the compiler required to emit stores to raw addresses?

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer, compiler-optimization

Two popular compilers (gcc, clang) emit a store instruction in the body of the following function:

```
void foo(char x) {
  *(char *)0xE0000000 = x;
}
```

This program might behave correctly on some hardware architectures, where the address being written to is memory-mapped IO.

Since this access is performed through a pointer not qualified as `volatile`, is the compiler required to emit a store here? Could a sufficiently-aggressive optimizer legally eliminate this store? I'm curious about whether this store constitutes an observable side effect with respect to the abstract machine.

Additionally, do C17 and C++20 differ in this regard?

Comment: That would depend on the hardware and how well the compiler understands the underlying hardware. If the compiler has been programmed with enough knowledge that it knows that the address does not have any special meaning and that memory location is not accessed again sure an aggrissive optimization may be used to remove that code.

Comment: Dereferencing something not allocated is [implementation defined](https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.lval#3.3) in C++. AFAIK C++ doesn't have the concept of addresses in the sense you're using it. Using `std::address_of` returns `T*`. So an 'address' as you're using it here is an implementation thing.

Comment: I wonder how this works in platforms where the entire memory is owned by the process itself like baremetal (no OS).

Comment: The C standard does not require a store, because assignment to a non-volatile lvalue is not an observable behavior as defined by the C standard.

Comment: @Jellyboy that's actually the context i'm curious about, but I didn't want to pollute the question with those details. :) In my case it's an ARM Cortex-M series micro with a memory-mapped peripheral IO system, and I'm curious if volatile is required.

Comment: @CharlesNicholson yes `volatile` should be used here, both to prevent reordering and to ensure it can't be optimized out as a dead store.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks, that's exactly the information I'm curious about. Do you happen to know what part of the C standard says that?

Comment: @Mgetz I fully agree that `volatile` _should_ be used here, but I'm curious if it's _required_ here to prevent the dead-store optimization.

Comment: @CharlesNicholson given that's implementation defined I would say **yes** because if you upgrade compilers later it could dead-store optimize it or UB optimize it. Both of which are stopped by `volatile`.

Comment: Note:  Not all platforms have the same addressing layout.  Even PCs can differ as to their content.  There are processors that use memory-mapped I/O and some that have special port instructions.  A compiler that can memorize all these different cases would be huge.  Maybe a better idea is to set up the Linker instructions (configuration) to match your target platform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C standard does not require an implementation to issue a store because C 2018 5.1.2.3 6 says:

> The least requirements on a conforming implementation are:
>
> — Accesses to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine.
>
> — At program termination, all data written into files shall be identical to the result that execution of the program according to the abstract semantics would have produced.
>
> — The input and output dynamics of interactive devices shall take place as specified in 7.21.3. The intent of these requirements is that unbuffered or line-buffered output appear as soon as possible, to ensure that prompting messages actually appear prior to a program waiting for input.
>
> This is the *observable behavior* of the program.

None of these includes assignment to a non-volatile lvalue.

Comment: Note that [C++ uses basically the same rule](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro.abstract#6).

Comment: It's also worth noting that even using `volatile` only prevents a compiler level re-order relative to other `volatile` stores/reads, it does not prevent an instruction or pipeline level reorder. That may require the use of intrinsics.

Comment: @Mgetz I don't think that's correct. Neither the C standard nor the C++ standard distinguish between what the compiler does in its own instructions and what those instructions make the hardware do. Either it says no re-orders or it doesn't say no reorders. There's no way a language standard could say "the compiler can't re-order but it can emit code that lets the hardware re-order" and neither the C standard nor the C++ standard say this. (This may be what some compilers happen to do, but it's not because any standard requires it.)

Comment: Not directly, @DavidSchwartz, but the C specification *does* say that it defines language semantics in terms of an abstract machine.  A volatile access is a side effect, and that side effect cannot be reordered relative to other side effects on or evaluations performed by the abstract machine, but the language has nothing to say about any effects of a volatile access that are not modeled by the abstract machine.

Comment: @JohnBollinger So how can that mean that the compiler cannot issue reordered instructions but can emit instructions that allow reordering? That makes no sense at all. The standard either allows or prohibits re-ordering. It cannot allow it in one place and not another when those two places are, for purposes of the standard, the same place. From the point of view of a language standard, the instructions are what they make the system do.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz you're confusing the standard with CPU architectures. I'm describing a situation that caused the Linux kernel some major headaches (and involved them solving it with the `cpuid` instruction of all things). The standard has AS-IF and `volatile` is constrained only by that. But it does NOT lock or prevent pipeline level reordering. So if writing to register A of a device **MUST** happen prior to writing to register B then you need something to force pipeline serialization. Which is NOT part of the standard. This is a major issue on RISC-V and AlphaAXP.

Comment: @Mgetz You said, `volatile` "prevents a compiler level re-order relative to other volatile stores/reads" but "does not prevent an instruction or pipeline level reorder". If you meant that some compilers happened to do that on some platforms, then fine. But it looked like you were saying that's some rule that emerges from the standard since nothing discussed prior to your comment was platform-specific. (And there is a very common but *very* wrong notion that this is what the standard says!)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I worded by statement very carefully and even revised it to specify that it only applied to `volatile` reads and writes. So it *only* applies to the abstract state machine and even then `volatile` can get hoisted (just checked, clang will do it). My statement was to remind anyone relying on `volatile` for IO that the CPU is not constrained by the standard. That was all.

Answer (score 4):

In C, it is expressly permitted to convert an integer to any pointer type, but that does not imply that you can use the resulting pointer to access memory.  Unless the conversion appears in the context of a null pointer constant (which canot be used to access memory), the result of the conversion

> is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.

(C17, 6.3.2.3/5)

"Implementation-defined" leaves abundant scope for subsequent accesses to the supposedly pointed-to object to have behavior that does not involve accessing memory, well beyond performing a trap or exhibiting the (unspecified) effects of a misaligned access or even exhibiting UB courtesy of a strict-aliasing violation.

Only if you get past all that do you reach the issues surrounding non-`volatile` access that @EricPostpischil brings up in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70426134/2402272).

The bottom line is that if you are writing for a freestanding implementation, which is the only context in which it makes any sense at all to try to perform an access such as in the example code, then you need to consult your implementation's documentation about how to access absolute addresses.

As far as I am aware, the same conclusion applies to C++.

Comment: This is indeed only for a freestanding implementation. Thanks for the details!

Comment: To be extremely pedantic, the reason I chose "char *" as the type for this example was to avoid a possibly-tangential sub-discussion about strict aliasing and the UB minefield. Reading your answer makes me wonder if I'm misunderstanding, though?

Comment: @CharlesNicholson, I don't think that the specific example presented poses a risk of misaligned access as C defines that, and I know it is fine with respect to strict aliasing, because you are accessing memory via a pointer of type `char *`.  These risks do apply in the general case, however, and they are some of the ways that the abstract machine can model incorrect accesses.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response; that's my understanding as well. I appreciate your coming back to respond!